# Get `An existing connection was forcibly closed by remote host` when connecting to Azure Frontdoor with HttpClient

Tags: c#, azure, tls1.2, azure-front-door

We have some .NET code that calls Azure websites sitting behind **Azure Frontdoor**.  The code uses the an HttpClient to make the call in a very straightforward fashion.  We started getting the following error when calling our sites through Azure Frontdoor.

**An existing connection was forcibly closed by remote host**

- This happens with .NET Framework 4.6, .NET Framework 4.7, & .NET Core 3.1.
- The actual Frontdoor site name doesn't matter.  Anything ending in `xxxx.azurefd.net` generates this error.
- The same code can hit the applications directly without issue.
- I can replicate this error on different Windows machines.  My laptop is running Windows 10.  We've also seen this behavior on Windows Server 2012 and other machines running Windows 10. These are corporate computers that sometimes operate behind proxies, but they still generate the error even when not behind the firewall/proxy.
- We've suspected that it's some type of TLS related error because Azure Frontdoor only supports TLS1.2 if you're not using a custom domain, but adding the TLS12 explicitly doesn't seem to help at all.

The following code generates the problem.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    if (ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol.HasFlag(SecurityProtocolType.Tls12) == false)
    {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    }

    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
    Console.WriteLine($"Protocol: {ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol}");

    var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://anything.azurefd.net") };

    try
    { 
        var result = await client.GetAsync("someroute");
        Console.WriteLine(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        while(e != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            e = e.InnerException;
        }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Another note: .NET doesn't seem to be the problem.  The Frontdoor URLs will also generate a `Can't connect securely to this page` error in IE 11 and Edge on the problematic PCs.  Oddly though, they work in Chrome.  We considered cipher suites, but any adjustments there don't seem to help anything so far.

Comment: Been chasing my tail on something similar.  Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would first see if there's something going on with your domain - may be try with another domain (I found the following: https://tej153-g8bjc9ezbycvbyav.z01.azurefd.net for testing purposes).

Another issue could be the cipher suites mismatch between your computer and azure's endpoint. I tested mine on 2012R2, Win10/Win11 and all work fine. May be the servers need a windows update?

Finally, I would remove the following unnecessary lines

```
if (ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol.HasFlag(SecurityProtocolType.Tls12) == false)
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
}

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

and replace it with a simple             `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`

Full code pasted below

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        Console.WriteLine($"Protocol: {ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol}");

        var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://anything.azurefd.net") };

        try
        {
            var result = await client.GetAsync("someroute");
            Console.WriteLine(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            while (e != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                e = e.InnerException;
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```